# How to convert CURL command with python requests and retrieve results via API

Tags: python, curl, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I'm new to python and encountered problems passing the parameters below that I want to request from the server via API.

I'm using flask as I want this to be web based.
Step1: go to index.html and pass teamID `teamID = request.form['teamID']`.
Step2: Authenticate user via API & find data by teamID
Step3: Go to the page report.html and display results + save results as CSV file

```
import subprocess
import json 
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

#required parameters
myID = 12345 
teamID = 3456
includeSub = 0 
beginDate = "2020-03-20 00:00:00"
endDate = "2020-03-22 00:00:00" 
Type = 1 
authToken = "1245dgfdfg655432gf"
serverURL = https://myurl.com/env/re/

#optional parameters
Category = 1
fpDate = 1
versionP = "1.0"
-----------------
```

This is CURL command that I would like to convert into python requests format:

```
#Curl command that i need to covert to python requests format
 "curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"accessToken:" & authToken & "\" \"" & serverURL & "teamID/" & teamID & "/report\" -d $'" & commandBody & "'"
```

my code so far:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/reports', methods=['POST'])
def getmyTeamReport(authToken, myID):
teamID = request.form['teamID']
headers = { 'accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'accessToken': authToken,
        'userID': myID}
commandBody = {
  "teamID": teamID,
  "includeSub": includeSub,
  "beginDate": beginDate,
  "endDate": endDate,
  "Category": Category,
  "fpDate": fpDate,
  "versionP": versionP
}
endpoint ='/report'
r = requests.get(serverURL+teamID+endpoint+headers=headers+commandBody=commandBody)
json_object = r.json()
report_t = json_object
return render_template('report.html', report=report_t)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Could someone help with this? So far I tried the code above but received `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` or `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your python code that you have now?

Comment: Hi bmcculley! I updated my question, let me know if this is any good... still experimenting with the above code but can't get there... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [TrillWorks](https://curl.trillworks.com/), we have now an online curl to python converter.
So for:

```
curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"accessToken:" & authToken & "\" \"" & serverURL & "teamID/" & teamID & "/report\" -d $'" & commandBody & "'
```

You have:

```
import requests

headers = {
    '\\Content-Type': 'application/json" -H "accessToken:',
}

response = requests.post('http://&', headers=headers)
```

It is available [HERE](https://curl.trillworks.com/).

---

To avoid `TabError`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/reports', methods=['POST'])
def getmyTeamReport(authToken, myID):
teamID = request.form['teamID']
headers = { 'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','accessToken': authToken,'userID': myID}
commandBody = {"teamID": teamID,"includeSub": includeSub,"beginDate": beginDate,"endDate": endDate,"Category": Category,"fpDate": fpDate,"versionP": versionP}
endpoint ='/report'
r = requests.get(serverURL+teamID+endpoint+headers=headers+commandBody=commandBody)
json_object = r.json()
report_t = json_object
return render_template('report.html', report=report_t)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Links no longer work. You can use [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/). Another one is [trillworks](https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html)